# Azure Event Hub Consumer group event is processed twice by 2 different listeners (Azure function)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-eventhub

We have a consumer group created for an event hub in Azure. Two Azure functions from two different function apps are subscribed to same consumer group. These functions apps are in different regions. When an event is being published to event hub, we see the same event is being processed by both functions. Though our functions are idempotent, we want to avoid duplicate processing for the same event by both the functions? Is there an efficient way to allow event to be processed only by one region/function app/function?

Note: Both the functions do the same work. It is just provisioned for multi-region purpose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll want to check and be sure the same Blob Storage container is being used for both apps.  Otherwise, the triggers won't see each other and be able to coordinate partition ownership.  They'll end up fighting and neither will make consistent forward progress.  Note that we strongly advise using a Storage account in the same region as your Function instance for consistent performance.  In this case, since you have Functions in two different regions, you'll want to be sure that they're either close geographically or pick a mutually close third region for Storage.

Comment: sure @JesseSquire. let me check and see if that works. thank you!

Comment: looks like that was it. thank you @JesseSquire